# I checked this backend code using Postman. It sometimes works properly. But, sometimes, it does not work. What's the matter with this code?

Tags: javascript, backend, koa

I checked this backend code using Postman. It sometimes works properly. But, sometimes, it does not work. What's the matter with this code?

I used the technology koa.js. I create dao file, api file, and router file to handle the backend.

```
studentRouter.put("/:id", async ctx=>{
    var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
    var id = new ObjectID(ctx.params.id);
    let student = ctx.request.body;
    student =  updateStudent(id,student);
    ctx.set('Context-Type','application/json' );
    ctx.body = {success:true, existingData:student}
    ctx.status = 200;
})
```

Comment: `it does not work` can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the router file, please use the await ' keyword before these functions

```
addStudent()
getStudents()
getStudent()
updateStudent()
deleteStudent()
```

As an example

```
studentRouter.post("/",async ctx =>{
    const data = ctx.request.body;
    const post = await addStudent(data);
    ctx.set('Content-Type','application/json');
    ctx.body = {success:true}
    ctx.status = 201;
})
```